# Can someone find an episode of a show that ends on a battlefield after a planetary battle?

Tags: story-identification, tv

I am looking for a sci-fi show where soldiers are staging on a space station preparing for an assault on a planet. With all the soldiers on the space station, tempers flare and there is a brawl. A high ranking official has a female soldier love interest. The episode ends with the female soldier laying on the battlefield dead next to another dead soldier that looks like Charles S. Dutton, who is still clutching a trench knife.

Comment: Got anything else? American tv?  How about weapons or tactics of the fighters? Who were they fighting?

Answer (score 14):

This is the episode [**"GROPOS"**](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/GROPOS) from the second season of ***Babylon 5***.

There is a large military contingent on the Babylon 5 station preparing for a ground assault, with tempers flaring between the station's personnel and the soldiers, just as you describe.

[image]

Michael Garibaldi, the head of security on the station, falls in love with one of the soldiers (Elizabeth Durman aka "Dodger", played by Marie Marshall):

[image]

Also in the episode is Private Turnbow (aka "Large", played by Ken Foree):

[image]

At the end of the episode, Dodger and Large are shown dead, side-by-side on the battlefield, just as you describe.